# env command does not list SHELL environmental variable

Tags: bash

Below is the output of the `env` command:

```
[root@machine123 /etc/profile.d] env | grep SHELL
```

As you can see the output of `env` does not list the `SHELL` environment variable.

But when I print `$SHELL`, it is there:

```
[root@machine123 /etc/profile.d] echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

What is going on, why is `SHELL` missing from the `env` output?

Comment: What is the output of `declare -p SHELL`?

Comment: Below is the output 
[root@machine123 /etc/profile.d]
# declare -p SHELL

declare -- SHELL="/bin/bash"

Comment: Looks like the `export` attribute from the variable was somehow cleared (`declare +x SHELL` would do it, for example). How did you start the root shell?

Comment: if connection is SSH , SHELL variable is listed under env command,

but if i do telnet , SHELL env is not listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know your local variables use the `set` command:

```
set lets you change or display the names and values of all shell variables and functions
```

Try `set | grep SHELL`

`env` or `printenv` displays global (or environment) variables, `set` local ones (which include the environment variables):
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html

Answer (score 2):

If the shell you are running does not `export` this variable, it will not be visible to subprocesses, including `env`.

Expecting it to exist and to be set to a useful value (outside of a shell script) is probably not portable.  A sane (at least on POSIX) default is to assume `SHELL=/bin/sh` if it is unset.